# Graphhopper java, how to hide input text of latitude and longitude

Tags: java

Установил на локальном сервере web api graphhopper.  Подскажите как скрыть левую колонку , то есть поля для ввода координат латитьюд и лонгитьюд. При обзоре маршрута на мобильных телефонах видимость становится неудобной.

Comment: Как то так [При успешном выполнении XMLHttpRequest запроса в сервлет(java) перезагружается страница](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/870422/204920)